# ng-view not loading in bootstrap page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Here is my index.html page. The red.html, green.html and blue.html pages are not getting routed.

I'm sure it's an embarrassing syntax error somewhere in the code which as a beginner I am overlooking, please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#/!" class="list-group-item">Main</a>
    <a href="#!red"
       class="list-group-item">Red </a>
    <a href="#!blue"
       class="list-group-item">Blue</a>
    <a href="#!green"
       class="list-group-item">Green</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
  <script>
  var app=angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"]);
  app.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "main.html"
  })
  .when("/red", {
    templateUrl : "red.html"
  })
  .when("/green", {
    templateUrl : "green.html""
  })
  .when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue.html"
  })
  }]);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. If you open the browser devtools and look at the console, you can see both of them. The first is a syntax error:

```
  .when("/green", {
    templateUrl : "green.html""
  })
```

You have an extra closing quote, it should be

```
  .when("/green", {
    templateUrl : "green.html"
  })
```

The second error has [this link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$compile/tpload?p0=main.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found) which helpfully explains the other issue: `ngRoute` was split out of the main Angular bundle in v1.2.0, so you need to load it separately:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js""></script>
```